# Array map function doesn't change elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, array.prototype.map

In JavaScript, I have an array, which is

```
array = [true, false]
```

In some cases, I am trying to initialize this array

```
array.map(item => {
   item = false
})
```

After running the above code, the array is not changed, it is still `[true, false]`, so is `.map` not reliable sometimes?

---

ONE MORE QUESTION:
After running my below code, the array is changed. Why does it work in this case?

```
let array = [{id:1, checked: false}, {id:2, checked:true}]
array.map(item => {
    item.checked = true
})
```

array becomes `[{id:1, checked: true}, {id:2, checked:true}]`

Comment: .map function doesn't change original array, it returns another array which you should use.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

JavaScript Array map() Method

*)creates a new array with the results of calling a function for every array element and it calls the provided function once for each element in an array, in order.

Note: map() Method does not execute the function for array elements without values and it does not change the original array.

[more details](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp)

Answer (score 5):

Array map function is working fine. The **map()** method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.
**map()** does not mutate the array on which it is called.

```js
var array = [true, false]



var new_array = array.map(function(item) {
  return false;
});

console.log(array)
console.log(new_array)
```

Answer (score 4):

If your mapping is simple, you can do:

```
var array = [true, false];
array = array.map(_ => false);

console.log(array);
// [false, false]
```

Comment: Using an underscore as a variable name is sometimes used when you're not actually going to use the variable for anything. It's purely a style-thing.

Answer (score 0):

`.map()` method is not mutable, check out its return value:

```
var arr2 = array.map(item => false)
console.log(arr2)
```

In functional programming, it's recommended that values do not change often, and JavaScript borrowed it. At least for `.map()` and `.reduce()` this is true. Make sure you know `.map()` well.