# Reversing a multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I want to reverse a multidimensional array and have the code below so far:

```
currentPositionPieceValues: [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]

gameDetails.currentPositionPieceValues
          .map(row => row.reverse())
          .reverse();
```

This seems to flip it horizontally, but not vertically, if you see what I mean.

How can I get it to do both?

Comment: Are you assigning the result to a variable? because `.map` is going to create a new array, not mutate the existing one (reverse, on the other hand, does mutate its array)

Comment: could you please share an example with sample data with it's expected output? Your code seems working fine for me.

Comment: @ChrisG That dupe target has a similar desired result, but not really the same problem. Nothing in it would explain to the asker why their very similar solution isn't working (E.g. it doesn't make any reference to the in-place modification of `.reverse()`, or the new array created by `.map()`)

Comment: @ChrisG - That's not a dupe. That's reversing the inner arrays only. This question wants both reversed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do:

```
gameDetails.currentPositionPieceValues = gameDetails.currentPositionPieceValues
          .map(row => row.reverse())
          .reverse();
```

This is because [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) creates a new array, so the outer array will get not get reversed unless you reassign it.

The inner arrays are being reversed because objects are always passed by reference in javascript.

Comment: This is 100% a dupe

Comment: @ChrisG feel free to find it and mark it

Comment: @ChrisG - Why are telling me that instead of voting to close? There are no votes to close as of the time of writing this.

Comment: @ChrisG I have 5,514 close votes.... so sorry I spent 30 seconds and wrote up an answer instead of closing.... lol

Comment: It's not a 100% dupe, but it doesn't have to be. It shows the general way to do this and points out that you need to use the return value of `map()` which is a crucial piece of the answer. The other relevant dupe is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42242257/array-map-function-doesnt-change-elements

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. Thank you, that worked perfectly. I wouldn't have guessed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Map returns a new array. So when you do the final reverse you are changing the new array, not currentPositionPieceValues.

```
const arr = gameDetails.currentPositionPieceValues;
arr.forEach(row => row.reverse());
arr.reverse();
```

Comment: This is 100% a dupe...

Comment: This isn't about your record, it's about not teaching people to post instead of google, i.e. clutter up the site with duplicate content. You're not only encouraging this, you're contributing. If this is how SO works now, fine. But I don't think it does, or should.

Comment: @ChrisG - That doesn't change the fact that the question you listed as a dupe of this one, was in fact not a dupe.