# Why javaScript nested map() doesn't return the value as intended?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, nested-loops

I was doing this problem in leetcode when javascript map() method was not working as intended. The question is as follows.

> Given an n x n binary matrix image, flip the image horizontally, then
> invert it, and return the resulting image.
>
> To flip an image horizontally means that each row of the image is
> reversed.
>
> For example, flipping [1,1,0] horizontally results in [0,1,1]. To
> invert an image means that each 0 is replaced by 1, and each 1 is
> replaced by 0.
>
> For example, inverting [0,1,1] results in [1,0,0].
> **

1. TestCase 1 :  [[1,1,0],[1,0,1],[0,0,0]]

**

So I got the result as follows,

```
const flipAndInvertImage = function (image) {
    const flippedImage = flipImage(image);
    return invertImage(flippedImage);
};

function flipImage(image){
    image.map(rows => {
        return rows.reverse();
    })
    return image;
}

function invertImage(image) {
    image.map(row => {
        row.map((num,index,array) => {
            array[index] =  (num === 0 ? 1 : 0)
        })
        return row;
    })
    return image;
}
```

But why is that nested row.map doesn't return the value directly when I try it like this?

```
const invertImage = (image) => {
    image.map(row => {
        row.map((num,index,array) => {
            return (num === 0 ? 1 : 0)
        })
        return row;
    })
    return image;
}
```

Or like this?

```
const invertImage = (image) => {
    image.map(row => {
        row.map((num,index,array) => {
            let col = (num === 0 ? 1 : 0)
            return col;
        })
        return row;
    })
    return image;
}
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Your missing return everywhere ->  `image.map(` -> `return image.map(`  etc.  map does not mutate it's input, it returns a new array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Array map function doesn't change elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42242257/array-map-function-doesnt-change-elements)

Answer (score 0):

map always returns a new array, and you are not explicity returning the second map. Like:

```
const invertImage = (image) => {
//you missed the return here
return image.map(row => {
   //you missed the return here too
   return row.map((num,index,array) => {
        let col = (num === 0 ? 1 : 0)
        return col;
    })
    
})
return image;
```

}

Comment: "_you are not explicity returning the second map_" - Or the first map for that matter. That is still a problem.

Comment: Yeah, missed that. The first should be returned too.

Answer (score 0):

`Array.map` doesn't mutate the given Array. So you need to either assign the result of `Array.map` to a variable and return said variable, or directly return the result.
E.g:

```js
const invertImage = (image) => {
    return image.map(row => {
        return row.map((num,index,array) => {
            let col = (num === 0 ? 1 : 0)
            return col;
        })
    })
}
```

OR

```js
const invertImage = (image) => {
    const flippedImage = image.map(row => {
        const flippedRow = row.map((num,index,array) => {
            let col = (num === 0 ? 1 : 0)
            return col;
        })
        return flippedRow;
    })
    return flippedImage;
}
```

Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

> The map() method >>>creates a new array<<< populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.